# SQL SELECT query no results and no error

Tags: php, mysql

The website I'm programming requires a simple login page and in said login page I am trying to program for an error to occur when a user tries to login with an existing username and or email. No matter the SELECT query I put in no result is bound and I get no error so I'm very confused. I can INSERT into the database with the same MySQL connecting and the same column tags so I sure of no typo. I would appreciate any help and I am still a student so please forgive me for any obvious problems I don't see.
I should also mention I echoed every post and they are assigned correctly

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
    $pName=$_POST['username'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $s='asdfasdf';
    $formPosted = 2;


if(strlen($_POST['email']) > 2){
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM tbl_users WHERE user_email = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($eid);
        $stmt->close();
        echo $email.'= '.$eid.'<br>';
        if(isset($eid)){
            $email_error = '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                                    Sorry this email is taken.
                                  </div>';
                                  $row = 0;
                                  $error = 1;
    }}
    else{

    }
```

The echo is for trouble shooting

```
if($error==0){
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_users (user_email, user_name, user_penName, user_pw) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ');
        $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $email, $name, $pName, $pw);
        if($stmt->execute()){

        }

        $stmt->close();
        $mysqli->close();
        //header('Location: index.php');
        //exit();
    }

    $mysqli->close();
```

Here is my insert statement that is under the same connection. The $error works depending on the Isset issue but ive tested it and I know it works.

Comment: Where is `$eid` being set?

Comment: It is being used in the same page

Comment: what's the result `echo $eid`?

Comment: You need to add just after strlen if condition, $email = $_POST['email'];

Comment: The echo $email.'= '.$eid.'<br>'; results in $ff@ff.com=

Comment: Have you tried testing the query in the MySQL interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change from

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM tbl_users WHERE user_email = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($eid);
        $stmt->close();
        echo $email.'= '.$eid.'<br>';
        if(isset($eid)){
```

to

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT user_email FROM tbl_users WHERE user_email = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($eid);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
           echo $email.'='.$eid.'<br>';
        }
        $stmt->close();
        if(isset($eid)){
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought since I was only requesting record I wouldn't need a while statement

Comment: Welcome:) but you have to fetch record if you want to use selected field